# Adjusting default brightness upon boot

Tags: display, brightness

When I boot to ubuntu 12.04, the back light on my display turns off and I have to press the increase brightness button 4 times to get it to the desired brightness.

Is there a terminal command I can input for a default brightness?

Answer (score 0):

I use a small hack.

- You need `xbacklight`. Try running it from terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T), and if the package is not already installed, it suggests you to install. Follow the instructions.
- Commands you need to know. (Use a number instead of `<...>`) Aren't they self-explanatory?

  - `xbacklight +<increment>`
  - `xbacklight -<decrement>`
  - `xbacklight =<value>`
- Usually the range is 0 to 100. Running with no arguments shows the current value.

It is now as simple as setting the corresponding command to run automatically.

#### Simplest way:

Open Startup applications (Search in dash) and add an entry with command `xbacklight =25`. Use your preferred value instead of `25`.

#### More complicated way:

Cook up a bash script to detect time of the day and then set the backlight value, and set it to run on startup. Left as an exercise to the reader.

#### Even more complicated way:

Detect light from webcam and the precise position of your favorite electron, destroy universe, rebuild it, and then set backlight to your favorite number. Set it to run on startup.